# Add-AzureAccount : Federated service - Error: ID3242

Tags: powershell, azure, storage, adfs

I am finding this a bit of challenge. I got a account like HBala@contoso.com but when I enter my user credentials, it redirects to my organizational federation server I assume and not Customer ADFS.

> Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $Context -Container $ContainerName;
>
> > Add-AzureAccount : Federated service at https://sts.contoso.com/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed returned error: ID3242: The security token could not be authenticated or 
> >     authorized.: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
> >     At line:4 char:1
> >     + Add-AzureAccount -Credential $AzureCredential;
> >     + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> >         + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException
> >         + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.AddAzureAccount

Any suggestions on how to authenticate it alternatively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot currently authenticate to Azure using a Live ID / Microsoft account. You need to create an Azure Active Directory user that you can use to authenticate. See article [Azure Automation: Authenticating to Azure using Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-automation-authenticating-to-azure-using-azure-active-directory/) for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing valuable link.Following another blog/article, I had tried these steps as well to an extent, but finally found that as Co-administrator, I can't add the new user to directory and require service admin role to help on that. But, few areas, I dint remember myself  implementing. So let me give one more try!